# Getting the "javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect" Error

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

**What I Want To Do:** Send a basic email with the smtp.live.com host to email to someone using a Java Program using this code below:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport;

public class emailTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String to = "example@live.com";
        String from = "example@live.com";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.live.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");


        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        session.setDebug(true);

        try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));

            message.setSubject("Java");

            message.setText("Java");

            Transport trans = session.getTransport("smtp");
            trans.connect("smtp.live.com", 587, "example@live.com", "password");
            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Message Sent!");

        } catch (MessagingException mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**The Problem:**  When I try to send the email, I get this error.

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:322)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:172)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:121)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:190)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:120)
at emailTest.main(emailTest.java:39)
```

**My Question:** I just want to know what I'm doing wrong as I've spent a few hours trying to find different ways on how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I soon figured out what I was doing wrong.  I can't use Transport.send(message) to send the message.

**Changes Needed:** Instead, I have to use trans.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients()).

Here's the fixed code:

```
    import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport;

public class emailTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String to = "example@live.com";
        String from = "example@live.com";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.live.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");


        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        session.setDebug(true);

        try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));

            message.setSubject("Java");

            message.setText("Java");

            Transport trans = session.getTransport("smtp");
            trans.connect("smtp.live.com", 587, "example@live.com", "password");
            trans.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());

            System.out.println("Message Sent!");

        } catch (MessagingException mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Only the [sendMessage change](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#send) should've been necessary.